# Which customized UI way is better?

Tags: swift, function, performance, uikit

I am almost new to Programmatic UI.

I have been creating some custom UI components for my projects but when I check people's projects I found the way I create UI components is different than theirs.

The codes completely make the same function but in different ways.

What is the difference between these two codes?

```
func makeLabel(withAlignment alignment: NSTextAlignment,
               withFontSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> UILabel {
  
  let label = UILabel()
  label.textAlignment             = alignment
  label.font                      = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize,
                                                     weight: .bold)
  
  label.textColor                 = .label
  label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
  label.minimumScaleFactor        = 0.9
  label.lineBreakMode             = .byTruncatingTail

  label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  
  return label
}
```

```
  init(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment,
       fontSize: CGFloat) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    self.textAlignment             = textAlignment
    self.font                      = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize,
                                                       weight: .bold)
  }
  
  private func configure() {
    self.textColor                 = .label
    
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.minimumScaleFactor        = 0.9
    self.lineBreakMode             = .byTruncatingTail
    
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
  }
```

To call them in my VC is the same way.

So the question is which way is better for me to create custom UIs?
Are there any pros or cons of these two technics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is just a helper, you created a function that **Return** an UILabel

The Second one is a CustomView, it can contain a label, but it can also be composed of several elements, an image + label for example

In a custom view, you can also override methods like drawRect or add some other components: for example

```
var isSelected {
  didSet {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I use your example in my custom view? is there any chance to show me the way I can use it?

Comment: var isSelected: Bool = false {
      didSet {
          view.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .blue : .green
      }
    }